# Xcode 8 convert code to swift 2.3 not running in device target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have been converted my swift code to 2.3 version. App is running perfectly in simulator for all the version like 8.0+, 9.0+, 10.0. But it is not at all running on physical device, showing multiple errors like "Could not build module Frameworkname" and many more regarding frameworks and I am using some classes which were written in Objective C to my swift project those are totally showing errors while running in physical device. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: first tell me you updated code to 2.3 or 3.0. Because xcode 8 will work on 3.0

Comment: @JAck i converted my code to 2.3. For your information Xcode is supporting swift 2.3 also.

Comment: ok so you converted it into 2.3 and it's not working and it 's showing you alert for could not build framework. You must have problem with code signing from build phases. check it out first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I get rid of this issue, Its all about the Xcode issue, may be some files been deleted from the Xcode. Installing new copy of Xcode is resolved the issue.